# Magento2.4 Shipstation integration

Tags: magento2.4

Has anyone ben able to get a Shipstation plugin or integration working with Magento 2.4?
Was just told directly by Shipstation that they do not support 2.4 and have no eta for when they would start supporting it.

Has anyone been successful with modifying the plugin they offer that works with 2.3 to get it to work with 2.4 and if so how?

Comment: We are using with magento 2.4.3-p1. Shipstation version 2.2.2. We don't have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this official plugin for Shipstation from Magento Markeplace: https://marketplace.magento.com/auctane-api.html

Supported with Magento v2.4